# Align text of textarea left

Tags: html, css

I little problem but I can't resolve it, so I have a textarea and I want to align the text who is inside left, my code is :

```
 <textarea
     rows="3"
     cols="25"
     id="{{ form_add_gift.description_article.name }}"
     name="{{ form_add_gift.description_article.name }}"
     style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important;text-align: left;"
     class="form-control"
     required="required">
     {{ form_add_gift.description_article.value|trim }}
</textarea>
```

The texarea look like this : 
Please help me!! Thx in advance

[image]

Comment: add white-space:normal, no need to worry about white spaces anymore. check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just because your `_______{{ form_add_gift.description_article.value|trim }}` contains too many spaces at the beginning.

Simply remove the white spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You are giving space while providing input to text area, no css change require din your case try:

```
<textarea
     rows="3"
     cols="25"
     id="{{ form_add_gift.description_article.name }}"
     name="{{ form_add_gift.description_article.name }}"
     style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important;text-align: left;"
     class="form-control"
     required="required">{{ form_add_gift.description_article.value|trim }}
</textarea>
```

Comment: Better explanation. After close tag, i just put the text like you wrote, in the same line of close tag and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**CONVERT**

```
<textarea
 rows="3"
 cols="25"
 id="{{ form_add_gift.description_article.name }}"
 name="{{ form_add_gift.description_article.name }}"
 style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important;text-align: left;"
 class="form-control"
 required="required">
 {{ form_add_gift.description_article.value|trim }}
</textarea>
```

**TO**

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="25" id="{{ form_add_gift.description_article.name     }}" name="{{ form_add_gift.description_article.name}}" style="padding: 0px     !important; margin: 0px !important;text-align: left;" class="form-control"     required="required">{{ form_add_gift.description_article.value|trim }</textarea>
```

Basically , what you need to do is to remove the extra linebreak and spaces after the end of  tag i.e

```
<textarea>your text</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove spaces in textarea, or use `white-space: normal;` as a smart way to avoid spaces in textarea.

> Removed spaces

```
 <textarea
     rows="3"
     cols="25"
     id="{{ form_add_gift.description_article.name }}"
     name="{{ form_add_gift.description_article.name }}"
     style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important;text-align: left;"
     class="form-control"
     required="required">{{ form_add_gift.description_article.value|trim }}
</textarea>
```

> Not removed spaces, added white-space:normal;

```
 <textarea
     rows="3"
     cols="25"
     id="{{ form_add_gift.description_article.name }}"
     name="{{ form_add_gift.description_article.name }}"
     style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important;text-align: left;white-space: normal;"
     class="form-control"
     required="required">
     {{ form_add_gift.description_article.value|trim }}
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<textarea name="{{ form_add_gift.description_article.name }}" id="{{ form_add_gift.description_article.name }}" class="form-control" required="required"  rows="3" cols="25" style="padding: 0px ;  margin: 0px; align: left;"  >

      {{ form_add_gift.description_article.value|trim }}
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra spaces and linebreaks from your assignment of textarea value like:

`<textarea>{{ form_add_gift.description_article.value|trim }}</textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing space between `<textarea>{{ form_add_gift.description_article.value|trim }}</textarea>` like following code.

```
<textarea
rows="3"
cols="25"
id="{{ form_add_gift.description_article.name }}"
name="{{ form_add_gift.description_article.name }}"
style="padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important;text-align: left;"
class="form-control"
required="required">{{ form_add_gift.description_article.value|trim }}</textarea>
```